# Two correspoding sides of similar triangles are perpendicular

Tags: geometry

I don't understand why if two pairs of corresponding sides of similar triangles are perpendicular, the third pair of corresponding sides must be perpendicular as well.

Could someone prove it/ explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

The triangles $A=(0,0)$, $B=(4,0)$, $C=(0,3)$ and $A'=(0,0)$, $B'=(0,-4)$, $C'=(-3,0)$ are similar (in fact congruent) with $AB\perp A'B'$ and $AC\perp A'C'$. But $BC$ and $B'C'$ are not orthogonal

Comment: U wrong sir cos they are parallel so in infinity points they are perp

Answer (score 0):

You can get from one triangle to a similar one by a conjonction of translation, homothetic transformation and rotation. Here the rotation is $\frac{\pi}{2}$...

EDIT: in a larger sense of similarity, reflection is also a possible transformation. The fact that two of the sides are perpendicular guarantees that this is not the case here.